# How to go to next carousel item on click of a button inside carousel item

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a carousel in `Bootstrap 4` where I have a next button inside the carousel item. I want to move to next carousel when I `click` on this next button.

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval='false'>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner ">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="gotoNext1">Next</button>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/900x350/e8117f/fff&text=Image%201" alt="Image 1"/>        
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="gotoNext2">Next</button>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/900x350/9ACD32/fff&text=Image%202" alt="Image 2"/>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/900x350/FF6347/fff&text=Image%203" alt="Image 3"/>
      </div>
    </div>        
  </div>
</div>
```

Please, can someone help me to implement this functionality using `Javascript` or `jquery`?

I can move next or prev using carousel indicators but I want to move forward using the buttons.

See the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhn3r5mj/7/) for more details...

Comment: Down voted due to not all of the logic from the jsfiddle being included in the question, and the jsfiddle link being formatted as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.carousel("next")](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/#carouselnext) from `JQuery`:

```js
$("button").click(() => $(".carousel").carousel("next"));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval='false'>
  
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
       <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner ">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " id="gotoNext1">
          Next
        </button>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/900x350/e8117f/fff&text=Image%201" alt="Image 1"/>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " id="gotoNext2">
          Next
        </button>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/900x350/9ACD32/fff&text=Image%202" alt="Image 2"/>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/900x350/FF6347/fff&text=Image%203" alt="Image 3"/>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @SUNNY You're welcome, consider accepting the answer if helped you.